# vim cant source rgb.txt

Tags: colorscheme

I am trying to source `rgb.txt` or `hex.txt`, so that I can use color by name instead of hex value in my color scheme.

In my `~/.vim/plugged/vim-coogle/colors`, I have

```
tree vim-coogle/
vim-coogle/
└── colors
    ├── hex.txt
    ├── rgb.txt
    └── vimgnome.vim
```

with

```
cat hex.txt 
#37474f bg800
```

and

```
cat rgb.txt 
200 0 0 bg800
```

in `colors/vimgnome.vim`, I have

```
source rgb.txt
if has("gui_running")
  set background=dark
endif
hi clear
if exists('syntax_on')
  syntax reset
endif
let g:colors_name='vimgnome'
hi Normal           guibg=bg800   guifg=#FFFFFF                   ctermfg=white   # Does not work
```

And I am getting error

```
Error: vi vimgnome.vim 
Error detected while processing /home/rudra/Utility/configs/vim/.vim/plugged/vim-coogle/colors/vimgnome.vim:
line   29:
E254: Cannot allocate colour bg800
```

What is going wrong here?

```
hi Normal           guibg=#37474F   guifg=#FFFFFF                   ctermfg=white #works
```

obviously works. But I want to get free of typing hex value each time.

Kindly help.

Comment: Obviously, rgb.txt is not a VimScript file, and so you can't source it. In fact, all you can do is either to patch the distributed file or set the colors within custom function capable of expanding your color names.

Comment: put those custom color names into $VIMRUNTIME/rgb.txt. And do not source this file.

Comment: So there is no way to do that without root password?